# How do I set the window size to fit the contents in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: layout, window, compose-desktop

I have some content which is exactly 500x500 pixels which I'd like to show in a window.

If I set the window size via `state = WindowState(...)`, it seems to create a window where the size is actually slightly smaller, so the content gets cut off.

Quick test app:

```kotlin
fun main() = application {
    Window(onCloseRequest = ::exitApplication, state = WindowState(width = 500.dp, height = 500.dp), resizable = false) {
        Surface(color = Color.Black, modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
            Canvas(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
                withTransform(transformBlock = {
                    scale(500.0f, 500.0f, pivot = Offset.Zero)
                }) {
                    drawLine(color = Color.Blue, start = Offset(0.0f, 0.0f), end = Offset(1.0f, 1.0f))
                    drawLine(color = Color.Blue, start = Offset(1.0f, 0.0f), end = Offset(0.0f, 1.0f))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The result is this window of outer size 486 x 493:

[image: screenshot]

How do I do the equivalent of Swing's `pack()` to fit the window to the content?

Answer (score 4):

Found the answer in the docs here:
https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-multiplatform/tree/master/tutorials/Window_API_new

```kotlin
fun main() = application {
    val state = rememberWindowState(placement = WindowPlacement.Maximized)

    Window(onCloseRequest = ::exitApplication, state) { }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

It is simple

```
val windowState = rememberWindowState(size = DpSize.Unspecified)
Window(onCloseRequest = ::exitApplication, state = windowState) {...}
```

Comment: That makes the window take up the whole screen. At least with my example. If there's just a Button inside it, it seems to fit the window to the button just fine, so maybe it's no good if the content is a Surface?

Comment: this gave me a very small window as there were no contents inside.
I want window to always be full screen no matter what the content is inside

Answer (score 2):

The drawn window header is part of the selected area of the window size, it is possible to turn it off and use the composition elements to implement your own title bar

> undecorated = true

Simple

```
application {
    val state = rememberWindowState(
        position = WindowPosition(Alignment.Center), size = DpSize(1280.dp, 768.dp)
    )
    Window(
        // Hide default window title
        undecorated = true
    )
    {
        AppView()
    }
    
    // You custom title bar
    AppWindowTitleBar(
                { state.isMinimized = !state.isMinimized },
                { exitApplication() }
            )
}

@Composable
fun WindowScope.AppWindowTitleBar(onMinimize: () -> Unit, onClose: () -> Unit) {
    AppDraggableArea()
    Box(Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
        Row(Modifier.align(Alignment.TopEnd).padding(horizontal = 8.dp)) {
            IconButton(onClick = onMinimize) {
                // minimize button
            }
            IconButton(onClick = onClose) {
                // close button
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
private fun WindowScope.AppDraggableArea() = WindowDraggableArea {
    Box(
        Modifier.fillMaxWidth().height(18.dp)/*.offset(y = 2.dp)*/
            .padding(horizontal = 160.dp)
            .shadow(4.dp, RoundedCornerShape(4.dp, 4.dp, 12.dp, 12.dp), ambientColor = Color.White)
            .background(Colors.DarkBlue)
    )
}
```

Comment: Now if only I could access the OS routines for drawing the bits of the window, LOL

Comment: Look, it's very easy to create your own window removal elements. https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-multiplatform/tree/396413168fbb4eb31eeb7fbc7da3ac66cabf21d4/tutorials/Window_API_new#draggable-window-area

Comment: By using your own window title, you have complete control over the contents of the window. If you need the contents of a window 500 * 500, then you draw your title, for example, with a height of 24dp and under it an area of ​​500 * 500, then you create a window with a width of 500 and a height of 524

Comment: This is useful in any case and something I've taken into consideration because I think I will eventually want the window to be draggable. But it doesn't solve the core question of how to have the window sized to fit the contents. What I think I might have to do is measure the contents up-front somehow.